# prevent googlebot adding to cart url ?action=buy_now

Tags: php, robots.txt

How Can I prevent googlebot and other bots adding content to the website shopping cart? each url has the following on the end

```
 product.php?action=buy_now&products_id=255453
```

I see in robots text I can deny certain php files from bots for example by adding
`Disallow: /products.php` but I dont want to block products.php I only want to block the buy now part so the bots cannot add content to the cart.

I tried Disallow: `/*action=buy_now*` but it didnt work. :( any ideas?

thanks

Comment: add it as an excluded parameter in webmastertools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use javascript to create checkout links.
You can write a simple js function to create the same url and redirect the user.
For example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goBuy(255453)">Buy</a>


function goBuy(products_id) {
    var url = 'product.php?action=buy_now&products_id=' + products_id;
    window.location = url;
}
```

It will be better if you put this function in a seperate .js file, not in HTML. Google and other bots won't read this url.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your page:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'bot') !== false 
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'baidu') !== false 
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'spider') !== false 
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Ask Jeeves') !== false  
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'slurp') !== false    
    || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'crawl') !== false) 
    {    
        Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );    
        Header( "Location: ".__PS_BASE_URI__);    exit; 
    }
```